# High resolution image not displaying in image view when view in full screen mode?

Tags: android, imageview, fullscreen, mode

I am displaying an image in full screen mode in samsung tab2,but whenever going to display large image then nothing display in the image view.

image_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_repet_"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFullImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

FullImageActivity.java:-

```
    ImageView imgFullImage;

    String dispFilename;
    String fileUrl;
    Bitmap bitmap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_view);

        imgFullImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgFullImage);

        fileUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("fileurl");
        dispFilename=getIntent().getExtras().getString("dispFilename");

            imgFullImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

                bitmap=decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(fileUrl,
        getDeviceWidth(FullImageActivity.this),getDeviceHeight(FullImageActivity.this));

               Log.e("Fill Image Size in 
                 Bytes","====>"+bitmap.getByteCount());     
        Log.e("Bitmap width & height","===>"+bitmap.getWidth() +"x"+bitmap.getHeight());
                imgFullImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    }

  public static int getDeviceWidth(Activity activity) {
        int deviceWidth = 0;

        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            deviceWidth = size.x;
        } else {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            deviceWidth = display.getWidth();
        }
        return deviceWidth;
    }

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static int getDeviceHeight(Activity activity) {
    int deviceHeight = 0;

    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        deviceHeight = size.y;
    } else {
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        deviceHeight = display.getHeight();
    }
    return deviceHeight;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String pathName,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Log:-

```
12-13 13:31:45.238: E/Fill Image Size in Bytes(24036): ====>15668224
12-13 13:31:45.238: E/Bitmap width & height(24036): ===>2288x1712
```

if any one have idea please reply.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you get any log, for example bitmap too large to display ?

Comment: No,I didn't get any error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String pathName,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: Its working fine for many resolution but in some image getting issue if i user image like 1532x900,2048x1365 res works fine and 2288x1722 then nothing displaying.and 700x464 then not display with size of tablet sceen but only equal to image size displaying.

Comment: which resolution u don't get images?

Comment: if image resolution is 2288x1722 then nothing displaying.

Comment: when i use 3000*4800 resolution image then also my code working fine ..i checked..please put your code here..

Comment: one more question. if i scale the image then image quality will affected.

Comment: image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

Comment: please add this and check if image quality is affected or not?

Comment: anyway quality decrease.... but i add the above line and also add on more operation on image Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, screenWidth, screenHeight, true); so it displaying image in full scree mode.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I want to do resize the images loaded from Res/Drawable folder using the resource ID how can that be done. I want load high resolution pictures as thumbnails.

Comment: @Mayur in my answer, 1st function its may be helpful to you.

Comment: @dipali: But in the first function you are giving path name, In my case ,I have default images stored in res/drawable folder. How can that images be resized.

Comment: not works for this image resolution is (height*width)2988*5312,

Answer (score 0):

Change to this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background_repet_" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imgFullImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am able view full image if image size is < 5-7 MB.But issue in large image size.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int getDeviceWidth(Activity activity) {
        int deviceWidth = 0;

        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            deviceWidth = size.x;
        } else {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            deviceWidth = display.getWidth();
        }
        return deviceWidth;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static int getDeviceHeight(Activity activity) {
        int deviceHeight = 0;

        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
            deviceHeight = size.y;
        } else {
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
            deviceHeight = display.getHeight();
        }
        return deviceHeight;
    }
```

you can use device height and width..and set this image in imageview..

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(viewHomeScreen);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        params.height = getDeviceHeight(activity);
        params.width = getDevicewidth(activity);
FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(viewHomeScreen);

        framelayout.addView(image, 0, params);
```

i hope this is useful to you

Comment: Thanks for reply,but My problem is large image displaying issue.Normal image displaying full screen mode very well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setImagesNew(ImageView img, String pathName,
            Activity activity) {

        Bitmap bmp = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(pathName,
                getDeviceWidth(activity), getDeviceHeight(activity));

        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        bmp = null;
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    }
```

use this function,imagesize will be compatible with your device height width..
your issue related to image ?
so this is best solution ....

Comment: decodeSampledBitmapFromResource() function not exist.Is it in built function.

Comment: thanks a lot.i commented in your ans.have you got any idea.what i have exactly issue.